# V8: Poor performance when trying to call a function 60 times a second

Tags: c++, v8

I am trying to integrate V8 into my game engine. This is how the engine currently handles the scripts: When the game starts, all the scripts are loaded, compiled and run. After that, the script engine tries to get a pointer to two JS functions called `setup` and `update`. If the functions exist in the source code, their pointers are placed in two `Persistent<Function>` objects. Then the engine calls the `setup` function once.

After this, the game loop starts, and my engine tries to call the `update` function 60 times per second (timing is handled by VSync, that's why it's 60). This is done with the following code:

```
void ScriptComponent::Update()
{
    if (!script_context->function_update.IsEmpty())
    {
        v8::Isolate* isolate = script_context->isolate;
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        // script_context->context is a Persistent<Context> and
        // script_context->function_update is a Persistent<Function>
        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = script_context->context.Get(isolate);
        script_context->function_update.Get(isolate)->Call(context, context->Global(), 0, {});
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but for some reason it brings the CPU usage up to ~20% and the fps down to about 30-45 FPS with occasional lag spikes. But if I comment out this code, I get an average CPU usage of 1% and a solid 60 FPS.

Is there any way I could optimize the code above so it doesn't take that long to execute?

Comment: Are you running an optimized build (not a "debug" or unoptimized build)?  What are the compiler flags you used when building the application?  All this information needs to be specified.

Comment: Thank you, I was running it in debug, the release seems fine. I will put that in an answer. That's a face-palm moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having performance issues with V8, make sure you run the program with the **Release**  version and **not Debug**.

Comment: This pretty much generalizes to any C/C++ program ;-)